# Jmeter resolution variable with remote

Tags: jmeter

I have a Jmeter script with a variable define in test Plan

```
SCRIPT_DIR  ${__groovy(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__groovy(File.separator,)}
INPUT_DIR   ${SCRIPT_DIR}./../data
RESULT_DIR  ${SCRIPT_DIR}./../resultat
RUN_ID  ${__P(runID, ${__time(yyyy'-'MM'-'dd_HH'h'mm'm'ss's',)})}
```

RESULT_DIR is used to define the location of my Simple Data Write and my Summary Report

```
${RESULT_DIR}${SLASH}${RUN_ID}${SLASH}errors.xml
${RESULT_DIR}${SLASH}${RUN_ID}${SLASH}rapport_summary.csv
```

I want to execute my script in distributed mode with two instances, VM1 and VM2

On each VM, I have start my jmeter-server and they are OK

```
[user@vm1]$ ./script/lance_jmeter_with_config_mode_server.sh
Created remote object: UnicastServerRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:45595](local),objID:[2ff2de01:18e896a8f94:-7fff, 7070060110512970506]]]
```

Then I start my script in remote mode (-r) and it's ok

```
$JMETER_HOME/bin/jmeter.sh -r -n -t /home/user/script/myscript.jmx -G$/home/user/config/myconf.properties -j /home/user/resultat/jmeter.log

Starting the test on host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx @ March 29, 2024 9:54:44 AM CET (1711702484330)
```

But on my directory, when Jmeter create the "resultat" folder, the variables are not translated. Folder is name "${SCRIPT_DIR}./../"

Is there any specific configuration for resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) documentation:

> Also, the variables are not available for use until after the element has been processed, so you **cannot reference variables that are defined in the same element**. You can reference variables defined in earlier UDVs or on the Test Plan.

So if you want to proceed with your current approach you need to:

1. Declare `SCRIPT` in 1st User Defined Variables
2. Declare `INPUT_DIR` and `RESULT_DIR` using 2nd instance of the User Defined Variables

More information: [Using User Defined Variables](https://portal.perforce.com/s/article/Using-User-Defined-Variables-1707509382889)